# RocketChat Livechat standalone preact app- Couldn't render livechat in browser

Tags: webpack-dev-server, preact, rocket.chat

I cloned the project Rocket.Chat.Livechat to run as standalone, installed dependncies ,while I do yarn dev , and it shows that ,

```
Local:            http://somehost:someport
On Your Network:  http://somehost:someport
```

Then in my browser when I try `http://somehost:someport` , ideally it should popup the livechat window??

I tried following too:
http://somehost:someport/livechat/1.0.0/rocketchat-livechat.min.js
but it shows

```
Cannot Get
```

Anything else should I do ??

Currently when I do this, I am getting the following error in browser console.:
[image]

[image]

Do the following error while I run the project can be a cause?

[image]